# How to post image and message on facebook without using browser in windows phone7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing windows phone app and I want to share message and image on facebook wall.I have share button and when I click the share button,Image and message must share on facebook wall.If user are not logged in then default login window must show and after logged in image and message will share.Only can use one page and it's included share button.I don't use browser to logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Facebook API by registering your application in Facebook where Unique ID will be provided to you. Use that key in your application and share the message and image on Facebook wall. Just have a look at [Facebook Login for Windows Phone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone) and [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/).

If you don't want to use Web Browser, You just need to get Facebook User ID and Password separately in your textbox and pass those values in Facebook Login(Refer the link which i provided).

In a single page, first get the user credentials, process in background and get authenticated. Then get the photo using PhotoChooserTask or CameraCaptureTask, get the message seperately. Pass those values. You need to work, do research and work it out. We cannot help you with full code. Just get the logic from above and start coding.

In simple words,

- Sign into FB, register your application, Get Unique AppID and use it in your application.
- Get user credentials and get him/her authenticated through FB.
- Pass message and Image and post on their FB wall.

You're done.